# putting function in a separate js file

Tags: jquery

I have the following in my main html:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('body').flvplay(songlist, {something});});
```

I wanted to move this to a separate JS file and make a function call from the main html.  I created the new JS with the following:

```
play()
{
jQuery('body').flvplay(songlist, {something});
}
```

Finally, I called the play function from the main html after including the new JS file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
play();
</script>
```

This is not working for some reason.  Is there anything wrong with the above? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare functions using the `function` keyword:

```
function play()
{
    jQuery('body').flvplay(songlist, {something});
}
```

Additionally, you deleted `$(document).ready(...)`, which is important because otherwise you might be trying to manipulate elements that do not exist because they have not loaded yet. You may want to modify your calling code to look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    play();
});
```

---

If you don't use the `function` keyword, the code in the referenced file will be parsed like this:

```
play()  // call the function `play` (which has not yet been defined)
        // as it does not yet exist, an error is thrown and execution is halted
{  // open a block (which is not useful here,
   //               since JavaScript has no block scope)
     jQuery('body').flvplay(songlist, {something});  // do something with body
}
```

Comment: Additionally, OP lost `$(document).ready()` in the transition, could be important depending on what `.flvplay()` does...

Comment: @lukiffer: Good point. I've edited my answer to include that.

Comment: I added the function keyword now and also included the document.ready function in the main html.  It is still not working.  It works fine if I have all the code in the main html though.

Comment: This is the webpage that am working on: http://grayradio.com/radio3.html
Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Ramnath: The code is trying to access `description`, but it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `function` keyword before `play()`

```
function play()
{
    jQuery('body').flvplay(songlist, {something});
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have added it now but still no luck.